# Not able to open the DocumentDirectoryPath in react native

Tags: android, react-native, android-13

**Android 13 - OS Specific issue**

I have download the zip file in DocumentDirectoryPath but when i am trying to open the file with different solution i am not able to open it.

```
Solution - 1. await Linking.openURL(⁠ file://${zipFilePath} ⁠, mimeType);
```

-- Lining is a facility in RN to open the file manager.
But getting error Unable to open file manager for BineryDocument.zip
I cross verified file exists

Solution - 2. React-native-intent-launcher try to use the package but it also not able to open the our zip file. Also this package have very less download

```
await IntentLauncherAndroid.startActivity({
    action: IntentLauncherAndroid.ACTION_VIEW,
    data: 'file:///path/to/your/file',
    type: 'application/your-mime-type',
});
```

Solution - 3 react-native-file-viewer  try to use the package but it also not able to open the our zip file.

```
try {
    await FileViewer.open(filePath, { showOpenWithDialog: true });
} catch (error) {
    console.error('Error opening file:', error);
}
```

Destination path

```
/data/user/0/co.binery.app/files/BineryDocument.zip
```

Comment: Nowhere in your post we see full path to the wanted directory. Unclear where you are talking about. `file://${zipFilePath}` tells us nothing. Like your other constructs.

Comment: @blackapps /data/user/0/co.binery.app/files/BineryDocument.zip

Comment: Please put that on the first line of you post. Not afterwards after reading your post. Replace the /path/to/file and so. Write a readable post.